# Transfer ubuntu18.04lts os from pc to laptop

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, data-recovery

My Dell 660s mother board bricked and I bought a Dell inspiron 15 5000 to replace it. Now to the questions 1. Can I boot from the old hdd via usb? 2. Wishing to avoid a lot of work what is the easiest way to rebuild my system 
I will dual boot as I do not want to void warranty. I have a deja-dup home dir backup on an external drive and no record of the software I was using to aid in reinstallation. Sure wish I had a complete system backup/clone. Any insight really appreciated...

Comment: Sorry I should have noted that I have a usb 3 hd enclosure.

Comment: First install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual boot environment. Then reinstall your old applications such as Chrome, DejaDup, etc. Then attach your external HDD in USB 3 enclosure and try to use dejadup to restore your files.

Comment: I was afraid of that, ug, a lot of work to get back up. I thought that having the old hd might help. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood. Are you saying you have two HDD's, one a backup and the other a working bootable Ubuntu installation?

Comment: That is correct. I have the hard drive from the bricked pc and it should be OK.

Comment: In that case after installing Ubuntu 18.04 in dual-boot environment, just plug it in and it will automatically be mounted under `/media` directory. Then browse the files with `nautilus` and copy files at will. No need for dejadup backups which can be difficult to deal with.

Comment: That is what I was hoping, it will save a lot of aches and pains. Thanks again. The last time I restored with deja-dup, what a mess.

Comment: Some people have found the deja-dup backups didn't even work when they tried to restore them... That's an even bigger nightmare. That's why it's always a good idea to navigate the backups and restore one file to a temporary directory and compare it to the original once a month or so.

Comment: Great idea! I do daily backups but never thought of that. I will put it on my calendar along with doing a system clone. Could be I will avoid some work next time something go bad.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can I boot from the old hdd via usb?

No. You can connect the disk to the laptop though using a cable that fits in the hard disk and fits into the laptop. Assuming SATA and USB 3.0 here is an example (eminent USB 3.1 to SATA 6G adapter 2.5 in case you need to find one similar for your situation):

[image]

This leave the disk exposed. Fine for a 1-time restoration of your files but not if you want to reuse it. Then you are probably better of with a hard disk casing.